# How can I check a signed jar file using Ant?

Tags: java, ant, code-signing

I sign jar files with the Ant [signjar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/signjar.html) and now I want to test before deploy.

I can check with

```
jarsigner -verify sbundle.jar
```

but I do not know if it is possible to do the same with Ant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative would be to base your build on a maven script.
Maven does propose the [**`jarsigner:verify`** plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jarsigner-plugin/verify-mojo.html)

If that is not a valid possibility, you still can use the [`Exec` Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) to directly call the `jarsigner` command.
If the return code is correctly set, you can add the attribute `failonerror` (Stop the build process if the command exits with a return code other than 0.)

Answer (score 4):

The following Ant code can be used for verifying JAR-file signatures. The script will *fail* as soon as it encounters a JAR-file where the signature is not valid or where it is missing.

Note that **ant-contrib** is required for the **for** task.

```
<!-- Macro to verify whether or not a JAR file is signed -->
<macrodef name="verify-signatures">
    <attribute name="filesetref" />
    <sequential>
        <for param="file">
            <path>
                <fileset refid="@{filesetref}" />
            </path>
            <sequential>
                <echo message="Verifying signature on file: @{file}" />
                <exec executable="jarsigner" failonerror="true">
                    <arg value="-verify" />
                    <arg value="@{file}" />
                </exec>
                <fail message="@{file} must be signed">
                    <condition>
                        <not>
                            <issigned file="@{file}" />
                        </not>
                    </condition>
                </fail>
            </sequential>
        </for>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<!-- Define the list of files to check -->
<fileset dir="p2repo" id="jarfiles">
    <include name="**/*.jar" />
</fileset>

<!-- Verify signatures -->   
<verify-signatures filesetref="jarfiles" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Ant conditions offer "issigned".

"Test whether a jarfile is signed. If the name of the signature is passed, the file is checked for presence of that particular signature; otherwise the file is checked for the existence of any signature. It does not perform rigorous signature validation; it only looks for the presence of a signature.
This condition was added in Apache Ant 1.7."

From [Ant conditions](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the VerifyJar Task in Ant to do this. Here is the link to Ant help
https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/verifyjar.html

Sample code for Verifying multiple JAR files at once.

```
<verifyjar keystore="mykeystore" keypass="abc"
          storepass="abc" alias="myalias">
    <path>
        <fileset dir="${build.dir}/signedjar" includes="**/*.jar" />
    </path>
</verifyjar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @torkildr's answer.

It's possible to make macro pass nested path or fileset to [ant-contrib for task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html).

```
<target name="verify-artifacts" description="Just an example of usage">
    <verify-artifacts>
        <fileset dir="${project.ear.dir}" includes="*.*ar"/>
    </verify-artifacts>
</target>

<macrodef name="verify-artifacts">
    <element name="artifact-path" implicit="true"/>
    <sequential>
        <for param="file">
            <artifact-path/>
            <sequential>
                <verify-artifact file="@{file}"/>
            </sequential>
        </for>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<macrodef name="verify-artifact">
    <attribute name="file"/>
    <attribute name="alias" default="${artifact.sign.keystore.alias}"/>
    <attribute name="keystore" default="${artifact.sign.keystore.path}"/>
    <attribute name="password" default="${artifact.sign.keystore.password}"/>
    <sequential>
        <if>
            <istrue value="${artifact.sign.enabled}"/>
            <then>
                <echo message="Trying to verify @{file} with alias @{alias} from @{keystore}"/>
                <required-macro-param value="@{alias}" prop="artifact.sign.keystore.alias"/>
                <required-macro-param value="@{keystore}" prop="artifact.sign.keystore.path"/>
                <required-macro-param value="@{password}" prop="artifact.sign.keystore.password"/>
                <fail message="Keystore path '@{keystore}' not found">
                    <condition>
                        <not><available file="@{keystore}" type="file"/></not>
                    </condition>
                </fail>
                <fail message="Artifact '@{file}' not found">
                    <condition>
                        <not><available file="@{file}" type="file"/></not>
                    </condition>
                </fail>
                <!-- jarsigner -verify -keystore @{keystore} -storepass @{password} @{file} @{alias} -->
                <exec executable="jarsigner" failonerror="true">
                    <arg value="-verify"/>
                    <arg value="-keystore"/>
                    <arg value="@{keystore}"/>
                    <arg value="-storepass"/>
                    <arg value="@{password}"/>
                    <arg value="@{file}"/>
                    <arg value="@{alias}"/>
                </exec>
            </then>
        </if>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<macrodef name="required-macro-param">
    <attribute name="prop"/>
    <attribute name="value"/>
    <sequential>
        <!--<echo message="@{value}"/>-->
        <fail message="You must set property '@{prop}'">
            <condition>
                <and>
                    <or>
                        <equals arg1="@{value}" arg2=""/>
                        <matches string="@{value}" pattern="^\$\{.*?\}$"/>
                    </or>
                    <!--<not><isset property="@{prop}"/></not>-->
                </and>
            </condition>
        </fail>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<macrodef name="sign-artifact">
    <attribute name="file"/>
    <attribute name="alias" default="${artifact.sign.keystore.alias}"/>
    <attribute name="keystore" default="${artifact.sign.keystore.path}"/>
    <attribute name="password" default="${artifact.sign.keystore.password}"/>
    <sequential>
        <if>
            <istrue value="${artifact.sign.enabled}"/>
            <then>
                <echo message="Trying to sign @{file} with alias @{alias} from @{keystore}"/>
                <required-macro-param value="@{alias}" prop="artifact.sign.keystore.alias"/>
                <required-macro-param value="@{keystore}" prop="artifact.sign.keystore.path"/>
                <required-macro-param value="@{password}" prop="artifact.sign.keystore.password"/>
                <fail message="Keystore path '@{keystore}' not found">
                    <condition>
                        <not><available file="@{keystore}" type="file"/></not>
                    </condition>
                </fail>
                <fail message="Artifact '@{file}' not found">
                    <condition>
                        <not><available file="@{file}" type="file"/></not>
                    </condition>
                </fail>
                <signjar jar="@{file}" alias="@{alias}" keystore="@{keystore}" storepass="@{password}"/>
                <fail message="Signature check failed">
                    <condition>
                        <not><issigned file="@{file}" name="@{alias}"/></not>
                    </condition>
                </fail>
            </then>
        </if>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<macrodef name="sign-artifacts">
    <element name="artifact-path" implicit="true"/>
    <sequential>
        <for param="file">
            <artifact-path/>
            <sequential>
                <sign-artifact file="@{file}"/>
            </sequential>
        </for>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<property name="artifact.sign.enabled" value="true"/>
<property name="artifact.sign.keystore.alias" value="alias"/>
<property name="artifact.sign.keystore.path" value="keystore.jks"/>
<property name="artifact.sign.keystore.password" value="pwd"/>
```

Comment: I prefer this answer since it actually checks that the jars are signed with the specified keystore. I had issues where the first script passed since it only checked they were signed and having issues with jars with different signers later.